# [Controller _mutableLayoutArrangements]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet, unrecognized-selector

I just converted a objective c class to swift 4 and while i'm running the code on the outlet property of button app is crashing

```
@IBOutlet var btnSelected: UIButton!
```

crashed at `btnSelected.isHidden = true`

[Controllet _mutableLayoutArrangements]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

[image: Error Description]

I tried removing and re connecting the outlets but issue didnt resolve and this issue is coming with every outlet

outlet is connected
[image]

Comment: display your code.

Comment: the app crashing on line "btnSelected.isHidden = true" and it in in viewDidload method

Comment: @Parv Bhasker i think your outlet is missing pls check

Comment: check proper outlet if already create outlet delete N new add Button with new name

Comment: @JigarDarji I checked that my outlet is connected and I even tried by disconnecting it and reconnect it again

Comment: @Parv Bhasker if you have demo than send me

Comment: @JigarDarji I am working on an existing project.

Comment: @VishalVaghasiya when i place a new button and created an outlet it worked. So do i need to create all the outlets again

Comment: give me your demo

Comment: I'm working on a live project and the view is already created with many outlets

Comment: i not get other so , i checking code then will be action

Comment: `btnSelected1` (screenshot of Storyboard) vs `btnSelected` (code)? Could you open the Storyboard as SourceCode (XML) (with an right click on it/Open as), and look for "btnSelected" in it?

Comment: Actually I was trying to find the solution for this so i just tried it by changing the variable name to "btnSelected1". yes my outlet exist in the storybord  as SourceCode

Answer (score 0):

goto storyboard and right-click on the **btnSelected** and check whether the **btnSelected** is having only one outlet, Also if you can attach a screenshot please do.

Comment: I updated the code with image and outlet is connected

Comment: In your code its `btnSelected` and in your image the name of the outlet is `btnSelected1` why?

Comment: Actually right now I was trying to find the solution for this so i just tried it by changing the variable name.

Comment: you also having @IBAction for that button?

Comment: Yes i have but the ibaction wull work only when i click button but the app crashes in the viewdidload method when i am setting the ishiddent property of button

Comment: please once check outlets of all the views in the controller from storyboard. The reason is it might happen that before you created a outlet for something and you deleted the outlet code from the code but forgot to delete the outlet from storyboard. please check each and every view

Answer (score 0):

Change the code with below code for button Outlet 
var btnSelected: UIButton?

And then go to Storyboard > remove the connection with button and reconnect it to btnSelected IBOutlet